# Set ContentControls Content Property from codebehind throws exception 'value does not fall in range'

Tags: wpf, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I got following xaml binding scenario working in WPF. Define `UIElements` in `Grid`'s ressources. Bind those static resources to a `ToggleButton`'s `Tag` property. On toggle button click assign the `Tag` property to the `Content` property of `ContentControl`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <TextBlock x:Key="t1"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="Text1" />
        <TextBlock x:Key="t2"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Text="Text2" />
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <ToggleButton Tag="{StaticResource t1}"
                      Margin="10"
                      Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
                      Content="T1" />
        <ToggleButton Tag="{StaticResource t2}"
                      Margin="10"
                      Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
                      Content="T1" />
    </StackPanel>

    <ContentControl x:Name="cc"
                    Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

The toggle button click just assigns the Tag value to the `Content` property.

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cc.Content = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag;
}
```

While this works in almighty WPF it is not possible in WinRT. WinRT complains with an `ArgumentException` 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'. I have no clue why?

For testing purposes I tried a direct assignment in the event handler, Which worked as expected:

```
 cc.Content = new TextBlock { Text = "Text1" };
```

To make it even more bizarre I tried this one in WinRT:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="cc"
                Content="{StaticResource t1}"
                Grid.Row="1" />
```

Result: **It works in the designer, but fails at runtime**. Even more clueless about that.

First of all what does the ArgumentException is trying to tell me? Second why is it working in WPF? What about the discrepancy between runtime and VS designer?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. All these sounds like a horrible hack, I mean, the `Tag` Property? What is this winforms? Why don't you create a proper ViewModel and use `DataTemplates` to dynamically define the `ContentPresenter`'s Content?

Comment: I know that there are far more elegant solutions like the one you suggest. But I am just curious why it's not working. Take it as a brain teaser.

Comment: Before it explodes with WinRT is the Tag value a TextBlock as expected?

Comment: It's a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock`.

Comment: In WPF the ContentControl content is of type Object, what is the Type in WinRT? perhaps its FrameworkElement or UIElement, so you may have to cast Tag(object) as a type its expecting (this is all pure speculation) :)

Comment: Does the TextBlock have a parent when it's a Tag like that? It can only be the child of one control at a time, so that might be causing this issue.

Answer (score 4):

In Win RT/Windows 8 Store Apps, the Content Control cannot contain an element that is already present in the view somewhere else. As it exists in Grid.Resources, it cannot be added to ContentControl.

I suggest making a DataTemplate instead in the resources:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="t1">
            <TextBlock Text="Text1" />
        </DataTemplate>
...
```

And in the button click something like:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var dataTemplate = ((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag as DataTemplate;
    cc.Content = dataTemplate.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
}
```

Note: I don't have the chance to test this.